# how to disable multiple checkboxes when i select radio button?

Tags: javascript

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<%@page import="com.ba.RetrieveDetails"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
history.forward();
function validate(logFile){

    var count=0;

    for (var i=0; i<logFile.length; i++) {
        if (logFile[i].checked) {

            count++;
        }

    }

    if (count < 1) 
    {
    alert("please select Log Fille(s)");
    return false;
    }

    }

</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Log Files</title>


</head>
<body>
<form name="LogFiles" action="RetrieveLogFiles" method="get" onsubmit="">
<%
HashMap hs=new HashMap();
hs=(HashMap)session.getAttribute("key");

session.getAttribute("key");

String hosts[]=(String[])session.getAttribute("hosts");
%>
<br>
<br>
<img src="BA_Logo1.bmp" align="right" alt="British Airways">
<table>
<tr>
<%
if(hs.size()== 0)
{%>
    <td><h3>Authentication fail OR Does not have access to UnixBox.Click <a href="Login.jsp">Here</a> to Login</h3></td>
<%
}
else
{
for(int i=0;i<hosts.length;i++)
{
    %>

    <h3><p><%out.println(hosts[i]+"\n");%></p></h3>

    <%


    ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
    al=(ArrayList)hs.get(hosts[i]);
    int flag=al.size();


    %>
    <td>
    <table border="2" cellpadding="4">  

    <%
    if(flag==0)
    {%>

    <td>
    <h3><p style="color:#FF0000">No Log Files to display</p></h3>
    </td>


    <%

    }else{
    for(int j=0;j<al.size();j++)
    {



        String lines[]=al.get(j).toString().split("\\r?\\n");



        for(int len=0;len<lines.length;len++)
        {

            %>

        <tr>
        <td><%out.println(lines[len]);%></td>

    <td><input type="checkbox" name="logFile" id="logFile" value="<%=hosts[i]+"$"+lines[len]%>"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="logFileView" id="logFileView" value="<%=hosts[i]+"$"+lines[len]%>"></td>
    </tr>


        <%
        }%>

        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
<%  }

}   

    }%>
<input type="submit" name="Get Logs" align="middle" value="Get Logs" onclick="return validate(logFile)" >
<%
}

%>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here when i press any radio button in logFileView.it has to disable all check boxes which are logFile? vice versa also needed. please help on this

logFileView is radio button and logFile is checkbox.Here multiple checkboxes and multiple radiobuttons iam using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using these [JavaScript code](http://jsfiddle.net/xTzNa/) 
First, it loops to get all elements(ex: check boxes), then add onclick event listener to them. Then the inside looping is to disable all radio buttons when click on the check boxes, same logics applied to radio buttons:

```
var logFiles = document.getElementsByName("logFile");
var logFileViews = document.getElementsByName("logFileView");

//To disable all radio buttons when click on any check box
for (var i=0, count=logFiles.length; i < count; i++) {
    logFiles[i].onclick = function() {
        for (var j=0, count=logFileViews.length; j < count; j++) {
            logFileViews[j].disabled = true;
        }
    };
}

//To disable all check boxes when click on any radio button
for (var i=0, count=logFileViews.length; i < count; i++) {
    logFileViews[i].onclick = function() {
        logFiles.disabled = true;
        for (var j=0, count=logFiles.length; j < count; j++) {
            logFiles[j].disabled = true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi @Handy its working fine but disabling when i click second time not first time for eg:if click two checkboxes or clicking two times on same checkboxes disabling perfectly. please hlep on this..

Comment: @shivatatikonda: Just update [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTzNa/1/). I've added a variable to store how many clicks on checkboxes. The counter will be increment by 1 on any click on checkboxes. If the counter reach 2, then it will disable all radio buttons.